# Accessing a 2D array between two friend classes

Tags: c++

My question is how to access and modify a 2D array defined in one class that is friends with another class. Below are some details on my question:

In `class A` I declare and allocate the appropriate space for my 2D array (pointer-to-pointer) u.

```
Class A
{
   public:
   friend class B;
   long double **u; 
   int fun;
   void make(); 
};
void A::make()
{
  long double **u = new long double *[nx];
  for (int i=0;i<nx;i++)
  u[i] = new long double [ny];
  int fun = 9;
}
```

`Class A` is friends with `Class B`; I need to use the array I declared in `Class A` in a function defined in `class B`. Below is my Class B:

```
class B
{
   public:
   void get(A*);
};

void B::get(A *pt)
{
   using namespace std;
   cout << pt->fun;
   cout << pt->u[0][0];
}
```

I get a Bus error on my second cout `pt->u[0][0]`. Is there a simple way to use this setup I have to access my u[][] array? I think that I get the error because the pointer points to the 1st entry of my array, thus my whole 2D array is saved in memory as a single row (thinking aloud here). I'm a Fortran guy so this stuff is a little new to me.

Any help or "pointers" to other helpful threads would be appreciated.

Thank you !

Alberto

Comment: Did you call `make()` first...?

Comment: And since u is public, the fact that class B is a friend of A doesn't really play a part in the problem (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Yes I do, I have a function that calls make() and get(). I get the correct "cout << pt->fun;" value when I compile and run the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you get error because `A::u` is not initialized ( in method `A::make` you initialize a local variable `u`, not member. You need to change

```
void A::make()
{
  long double **u = new long double *[nx]; // should be just u, or this->u.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your code: `nx` and `ny` don't seem to be defined anywhere, and in `make` you don't initialize `A::fun` at all, you instead set a local variable named `fun` which goes out of scope immediately.

As for your error, it *sounds* like the error stems from the fact that `make()` has not been called on `pt`. Ensure that `make()` is called on the instance you pass to `get`, otherwise the array `u` will not be allocated.

Comment: I omitted some details, like nx and ny. I do call on make() in my int main() part of my code. Here I pass the address of my class to the get() function (I think correctly) since I can compile and obtain the right value of "fun" to display on my screen.